# Fresh install on Alder Lake not using Intel gpu?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, gpu

I have a fresh 21.10 install on an Alder Lake system (12th gen intel.)

I noticed that my screen resolution was not native, and I could not change it.

I examined the Xorg log file, but I don't think it is even using an Intel driver?

Is there something special I need to do, to use an Intel GPU from Alder Lake CPU?

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    22.164] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1122.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[    22.164] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    22.164] Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
[    22.164] Current Operating System: Linux deca 5.13.0-28-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 13 17:41:06 UTC 2022 x86_64
[    22.164] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic root=UUID=51edf4df-659c-4b90-9fcd-2e45ca0064db ro intel_pstate=passive
[    22.164] Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:07:57PM
[    22.164] xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    22.164] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    22.164]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    22.164] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    22.164] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb  2 17:23:36 2022
[    22.164] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    22.165] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    22.165] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    22.165] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    22.165] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    22.165] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    22.165] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    22.165] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    22.165] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    22.165] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    22.165] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    22.166] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    22.166]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.166] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    22.166]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.166] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    22.166]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.166] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    22.166]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.166] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    22.166]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.166] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    22.166] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    22.166] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    22.166] (II) Loader magic: 0x5638467fd020
[    22.166] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    22.166]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    22.166]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    22.166]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    22.166]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    22.166] (++) using VT number 2

[    22.167] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    22.168] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:4680:1043:8694 rev 12, Mem @ 0x6002000000/16777216, 0x4000000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    22.168] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    22.168] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    22.170] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.170]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.170]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    22.170] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[    22.170] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[    22.170] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    22.170] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    22.170] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    22.170] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.170]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.20.13
[    22.170]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.170]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    22.170] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    22.170] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.170]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 0.5.0
[    22.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    22.171] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    22.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    22.171] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.171]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 2.5.0
[    22.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    22.171] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    22.171] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    22.171] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    22.171] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    22.171] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    22.171] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    22.171] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    22.171] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.171]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 0.0.2
[    22.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    22.171] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[    22.171] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.171] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    22.171] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    22.171] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    22.171] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    22.171] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[    22.171] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
[    22.171] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
[    22.171] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    22.171] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    22.171] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    22.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    22.171] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.171]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.171]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    22.171] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    22.171] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    22.171] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    22.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    22.172] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.172]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.1.0
[    22.172]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    22.172] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    22.172] (II) Unloading vesa
[    22.172] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    22.172] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    22.172] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    22.173] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[    22.174] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    22.174] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    22.174] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    22.209] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    22.209] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    22.209] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    22.209] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    22.209] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    22.209] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    22.224] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    22.224] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    22.224] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    22.224] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    22.225] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.225]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.1.0
[    22.225]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    22.225]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    22.225] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    22.225] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 24 paused 0
[    22.225] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    22.225] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    22.226] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    22.228] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.228] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.228] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    22.228] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    22.228] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    22.228] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    22.228] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    22.228] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.228] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.228] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    22.228] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    22.228] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    22.229] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 27 paused 0
[    22.229] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    22.229] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    22.229] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    22.229] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.229] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.229] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    22.229] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[    22.229] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    22.229] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    22.229] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    22.229] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.229] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.229] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    22.229] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    22.229] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    22.230] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 28 paused 0
[    22.230] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    22.230] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    22.230] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    22.230] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.230] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.230] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    22.230] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[    22.230] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    22.230] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    22.230] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    22.230] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.230] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    22.230] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[    22.230] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    22.230] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse'
[    22.231] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 29 paused 0
[    22.231] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    22.231] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    22.231] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    22.231] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    22.231] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device set to 1000 DPI
[    22.231] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
[    22.231] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device removed
[    22.231] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0002/input/input3/event3"
[    22.231] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    22.231] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    22.231] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    22.231] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    22.231] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    22.232] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    22.232] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device set to 1000 DPI
[    22.232] (II) event3  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
[    22.232] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    22.232] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    22.232] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    22.232] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Eee PC WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event4)
[    22.232] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    22.232] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[    22.232] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 30 paused 0
[    22.232] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[    22.232] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    22.232] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    22.232] (II) event4  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.232] (II) event4  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    22.232] (II) event4  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device removed
[    22.232] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input4/event4"
[    22.232] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Eee PC WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    22.233] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    22.233] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    22.233] (II) event4  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    22.233] (II) event4  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    30.557] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SN TECH    USBGamingMouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    30.557] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    30.558] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    30.582] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SN TECH    USBGamingMouse (/dev/input/event5)
[    30.583] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    30.583] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SN TECH    USBGamingMouse'
[    30.583] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 45 paused 0
[    30.583] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: always reports core events
[    30.583] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    30.583] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    30.585] (II) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    30.585] (II) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device is a keyboard
[    30.586] (II) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device removed
[    30.586] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:258A:0013.0003/input/input5/event5"
[    30.586] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SN TECH    USBGamingMouse" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    30.586] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    30.586] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    30.586] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    30.586] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[    30.587] (II) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    30.587] (II) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device is a keyboard
[    30.618] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SN TECH    USBGamingMouse (/dev/input/event6)
[    30.618] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    30.618] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SN TECH    USBGamingMouse'
[    30.643] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 46 paused 0
[    30.643] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: always reports core events
[    30.643] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    30.643] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    30.644] (II) event6  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    30.644] (II) event6  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device is a pointer
[    30.644] (II) event6  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device removed
[    30.644] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:258A:0013.0004/input/input6/event6"
[    30.644] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SN TECH    USBGamingMouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[    30.644] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    30.644] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    30.644] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    30.644] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    30.645] (II) event6  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    30.645] (II) event6  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: device is a pointer
[    30.648] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard (/dev/input/event8)
[    30.648] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    30.648] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard'
[    30.649] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72 fd 47 paused 0
[    30.649] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: always reports core events
[    30.649] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    30.649] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    30.650] (II) event8  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    30.650] (II) event8  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    30.650] (II) event8  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: device removed
[    30.650] (II) libinput: SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: needs a virtual subdevice
[    30.650] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:258A:0013.0004/input/input8/event8"
[    30.650] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    30.650] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    30.651] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    30.651] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    30.651] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    30.652] (II) event8  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    30.652] (II) event8  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    30.652] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    30.652] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard'
[    30.652] (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72
[    30.652] (**) SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: always reports core events
[    30.652] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    30.652] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[    30.653] (II) libinput: SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard: is a virtual subdevice
[    30.653] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:258A:0013.0004/input/input8/event8"
[    30.653] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SN TECH    USBGamingMouse Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    30.653] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    30.653] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    30.653] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    30.653] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[    30.653] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SN TECH    USBGamingMouse (/dev/input/event7)
[    30.653] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    30.653] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    64.629] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[    64.629] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    64.629] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    64.637] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event13)
[    64.637] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    64.637] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    64.637] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event12)
[    64.637] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    64.637] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    64.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[    64.638] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    64.638] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    64.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event11)
[    64.638] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    64.638] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 59082.141] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 33ms, your system is too slow
[ 59270.876] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 16ms, your system is too slow
[ 59290.510] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 30ms, your system is too slow
[ 59933.146] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
[ 60146.789] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 25ms, your system is too slow
[ 60146.789] (EE) event5  - SN TECH    USBGamingMouse: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 60min). Discarding future messages.
```

There are no additional drivers I can install, see:

[image]

Comment: You probably need an even newer kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need linux kernel 5.16 or later.

And for now, you need to build that from source, after grabbing a kernel from kernel.org

See my [write-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979222/301166) on how to do that on Ubuntu.